# Symfony2 ManyToMany with attributes

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

I'm trying to manage a manyToMany relation with attributes in one view for delete/update/add.

This is my relation : a User can speak some langages with a level. So There are a table for Users, Langages and the third for manage the relation with the level.

This is my controller :

```
    public function gererLangueAction(Request $request, User $user){
    $form = $this->createForm(new ajouterLangueFormType, $user);
    if ($request->getMethod() == 'POST') {
        $form->bind($request);
        if ($form->isValid()) {
            $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
            if(!empty($request->request->get("intranet_rh_gererlangue")['userLangues']))
                 foreach($request->request->get("intranet_rh_gererlangue")['userLangues'] as $langue)
                 {
                        $l = $em->getRepository('IntranetRhBundle:Langue')->findOneById($langue['langue']);
                        $userLangues = new UserLangue();
                        $userLangues->setUser($user);
                        $userLangues->setLangue($l);
                        $userLangues->setNiveau($langue['niveau']);
                        $user->addUserLangue($userLangues);
                        $em->persist($userLangues);
                }
            $em->flush();
            $this->get('session')->getFlashBag()->add('success', "Les langues de ". $user->getNom() ." ". $user->getPrenom() . " ont été modifiées avec succès !");
            return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('intranet_rh_homepage'));
        }else
            $this->get('session')->getFlashBag()->add('danger', "Erreur de formulaire !");  
    }
    return $this->render('IntranetRhBundle:User:gererLangue.html.twig',array('user' => $user, 'form' => $form->createView()));
}
```

My view is ok, my JS allow me to add and delete and I can update and delete some languages if they already exist.

But when I want to add a language, I have this message :

"Entity of type Intranet\RhBundle\Entity\UserLangue is missing an assigned ID for field 'user'. The identifier generation strategy for this entity requires the ID field to be populated before EntityManager#persist() is called. If you want automatically generated identifiers instead you need to adjust the metadata mapping accordingly. "

But I don't understand why because of my doctrine annotation on each class :

for UserLangue :

```
/**
* @ORM\Id
* @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Intranet\UserBundle\Entity\User", inversedBy="userLangues")
* @ORM\JoinColumn(name="user_id", referencedColumnName="id", nullable=false)
*/
private $user;
```

For User :

```
    /**
* @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Intranet\RhBundle\Entity\UserLangue", mappedBy="user", cascade={"persist", "remove"}, orphanRemoval=true)
**/
private $userLangues;
```

With adding and removing method.
I'm working on this bug since 3 days but nobody already had a similar mistake...

Comment: are you sure your User entity here is persisted to the database?

Comment: Yes I am sure because I test it with var_dump($em->contains($user));
$user is persisted, and $userLangues too...
But when I flush : error.

Comment: have you tried $form->handleRequest($request) instead of ->bind ? bind is  deprecated now

Comment: No change with it. No more error, but if it's deprecated I'll use it now !

Answer (score 1):

You can try to add `@ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")` in the annotation, but having a relation as the Id is not a very good ideea and I don't think it can even work. Try adding an $id parameter and set the relation as a different parameter.

Comment: I already try to do it. It's recommanded by Symfony since a specific version.

But I had the same error message with a single primary key with auto-increment and with a primary key composed by two foregin keys.

Comment: In fact, it's with this method I found the problem on User yesterday.
The message with there annotations was :
SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'user_id' cannot be null 
But I don't understand why because in the controller I can access to $userLangue->getUser() ...

Comment: I see, well the only difference from what I used is that I didn't have the nullable=false option and that I set the multiple keys in the constructor. Maybe try removing the nullable=false option.

Comment: Uhuh, Good job ! it reveals the real mistake : two things are insert...
One with the good user_id, the other with user_id NULL.

Comment: You are losing the $user over the loop? Maybe add smth like `if ($user) {` in which you can add all the logic.

Comment: I solve the problem. Thank's to you, I see the double insert and I realize my foreach on the data is useless. But it's this loop which insert the good line.
So, I have to loop on user->userLangues to setUser($user) and then, I persist $user and flush. Finish with no exception ! I can go back on my composed primary key for check : It's ok to use it.